# Bootstrap carousel control visible items in next row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My current carousel (`v3.3.7`) has 3 items, 2 of which are shown by default. When I click "next", I want to show the the 2nd and 3rd, then clicking on next have the 3rd and 1st, and so on.

Current pseudo-HTML looks like so:

```
.row
    .col-xs-6
        .title
        .text
    .col-xs-6
        .title
        .text
.row
    .col-xs-6
        .title
        .text
.navigation-controls
```

By default, as you'd imagine, I see: `1 | 2` and on clicking next, I see `3 | (blank)`

I've tried numerous variations of the [infinite loop javascript snippet hack several are talking about](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/infinite-carousel-loop), but all this does for me is add the next slide inside the `.col-xs-6` element, next to my `.text` and `.title`. What's more frustrating is that each of my `.col-xs-6` elements also contain my `.navigation-controls`, which frankly is getting on my nerves.

Bottom line, I need to create a loop without having to loop through my items until I have enough to fill my `.row`s completely (duplicating part of my DOM).

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried or a working fiddle/bootply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this is by introducing some plugin.
I would highly recommend slick slider: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

config for it would be:

```
$('.carouselWrapper').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  adaptiveHeight: true
```

});

Comment: Thank you, I will go forward with slick, as you've proposed.